# Click count using JavaScript for many buttons with default value '0'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick

I want to use a click count function in JavaScript to measure the number of clicks on a button in otree. The data should be stored in the database using a hidden input field.

The function should store the value '0' if the button has not been clicked and the number of clicks if the button has been clicked. The objective is to avoid error messages in otree due to empty input fields. In additon, I want to use the function for a lot of buttons (10-20 buttons).

Many thanks!

````
<button type="button" onclick="buttonClicked('num_clicks', 'num_clicks_feedback')">Click me</button>

<span id="num_clicks_feedback"></span>

<input type="hidden" name="num_clicks" id="num_clicks"/>

<script>
    let numClicks = 0;

    function buttonClicked(id, id_2) {
        numClicks++;
        // this stores it in the database
        document.getElementById(id).value = numClicks;
        // this just displays it back to the user
        document.getElementById(id_2).innerText = numClicks;
    }
</script>```
````

Comment: Just send an AJAX request every time a button is clicked instead of submitting a form.

Comment: You don't have any button in your HTML...

Comment: https://otree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html <<< and
https://otree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#buttons <<< you need to have some button that will do submit job.

Comment: For the submission of the page I will use the otree 'next' button. The other buttons are type="button" to show and hide content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass `this` to the `buttonClicked()` function and then store the click counter as a property of the button itself.

```js
function buttonClicked(btn) {
  btn.click_counter = (btn.click_counter || 0) + 1;

  document.getElementById('num_clicks_feedback').textContent =
    `btn ${btn.getAttribute('data-id')} has been clicked ${btn.click_counter} times`;
}
```

```html
<button data-id="foo" onclick="buttonClicked(this)">Click me</button>
<button data-id="bar" onclick="buttonClicked(this)">Click me</button>
<button data-id="steve" onclick="buttonClicked(this)">Click me</button>
<button data-id="321" onclick="buttonClicked(this)">Click me</button>
<button data-id="submit" onclick="buttonClicked(this)">Click me</button>
<button data-id="abort!" onclick="buttonClicked(this)">Click me</button>

<p id="num_clicks_feedback"></p>
```

Then when you want to update the database, you can just grab the property value from the button.

```
document.querySelector('button[data-id="submit"]').click_counter || 0;
```

Note: if you absolutely have to use an `<input>`, it's value will always be of type string. So unless you convert it, you could run into some issues if you try to do math with it later on.